# Update custom attribute from joined table

Tags: php, yii2

I have a User table which is joined with auth_assignment table to get the user role and display it in a gridview of user. The role attribute is displayed on the gridview but when i click the action button edit the form is loaded and the role attribute is empty.

I'm trying to be able to update the field from joined table directly in the user update action. Is it possible?

My model:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
  public $perfil;

public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'permissions' => 'Permissões',
            'first_name' => 'Primeiro Nome',
            'last_name' => 'Último Nome',
            'perfil' => 'Role',
        ];
    }
```

My index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        // ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'username',
        [
            'attribute'=>'perfil',
            'value'=>'authAssignment.item_name'
        ],
```

My _form.php:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'perfil')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My join in User model and acessing it in search model:

```
public function getAuthAssignment() {
    return $this->hasOne(AuthAssignment::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

if (Yii::$app->controller->id == 'user' && Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'index') {
            $query->joinWith('authAssignment');
 }
```

I want to be able to update the role attribute along with the others fields when i click the action column edit button.
I'm able to display the role(perfil) column in gridview but when i click update button the field comes empty.

[image: update screen]

How can i update a field that comes from a joined table?

Comment: You can write some code, which will update joined table.

Comment: So do it, without any specific problem and relevant code we can't help.

Comment: @Yupik Ok, i'll update my question.

Comment: you have specified a rule for Role field in the Model?

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes it's marked as safe

Comment: When you access on the attribute of joined table i remember that you must use something like this : $model->authAssignment['item_name'] where item_name i presume it's a column of table authAssignment

Comment: @Sfili_81 thanks. It's showing on the form now but i'm unable to update it.
When i make the changes and click update it doesn't change the value. Any clue?

Comment: Show us your controller, where you receive the data with the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the joined table field i instantiated the auth_assignment table in the update function and when the save button is clicked i assign the posted value to the item_name field. Here is my update function:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    // display joined table field in the update form
    $model->perfil = $model->authAssignment['item_name'];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        // get the auth_assignment table
        $authAssig = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one();

        // update field using postedform value
        $authAssig->item_name = Yii::$app->request->post()['User']['perfil'];

        if ($model->save() && $authAssig->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```